# Clojure cmdline start use maven pom file

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

For example:

If I specific the path ~/.m2/repository

When I import some dependencies in cmd line like follow then 
it can find the jar location by my maven pom file.

```
[yf@local]java -cp clojure-1.8.0.jar clojure.main
Clojure 1.8.0
user=>
user=> (:import org.apache.commons.lang StringUtils)
```

Answer (score 0):

Clojure itself does not do any dependency management at all. For that you need [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org), which is clojure's build and dependency management tool, which can work with Maven repo's.

Steps:

1. install lein script
2. run `lein self-install`
3. do `lein new <projectname>` to create a new project in the current dir
4. go into the project dir and edit the `project.clj` file
5. add [org.apache.commons\commons-lang3 "3.4"] to the :dependencies vector
6. run `lein repl` to update the dependencies / get dependencies from local and start a repl of the project

Also, the `(:import [org.apache.commons.lang StringUtils])` can only be used within the `(ns )` block. Used outside of the ns block you should do a `(import [org.apache.commons.lang StringUtils])`